# How do I do popen() in Windows Console App

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++17

## A Package like popen

I have spent some time researching the code that people have written to send data to and receive data from sub programs using

- CreateProcess.lpCommandLine
- STARTUPINFO.hStdInput as a file
- STARTUPINFO.hStdInput as a pipe
- STARTUPINFO.hStdOutput as a file
- STARTUPINFO.hStdOutput as a pipe

The specific problems handled are

- When to use cmd.exe
- How to stay in the same window
- How to detect when to send data

Answer (score 0):

The code is

```
#include   <stdio.h>
#include     <stdlib.h>
#include     <stdarg.h>
#include   <conio.h>
#include   <windows.h>
#include   <process.h>
#include     <sys/stat.h>

#if _MSC_VER < 1900
#define CONSTEXPR const
#else
#define CONSTEXPR constexpr
#endif

#if _DEBUG
#define NULL_OP stdout
#else
#define NULL_OP NULL
#endif


typedef short Cc;
#define OK 0
#define nullptr (0)

#define PATHCHR ';'
#define DIRSEPCHAR  '\\'

#define NFILEN 256

#define in_range(a,b,c) ((unsigned)((a)-(b)) <= (unsigned)((c)-(b)) && ((signed)c)-(b) >= 0)


char * concat(char * tgt, ...)
{
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, tgt);

{ char * s;
  tgt[0] = 0;

  while ((s = va_arg(ap, char *)) != nullptr)
    strcat(tgt, s);

  return tgt;
}}

                    /* at most n chars including the 0 */

char * strpcpypfx(char * t_, const char * s_, int n_, char term)

{ short n;
  char ch;
  const char * s = s_;
  char * t = t_;

  for (n = -1; ++n < n_ && (ch = s[n]) != 0 && ch != term;
      )
    t[n] = ch;
  
  t[n] = 0;

  return t_;
}

                    /* at most n chars including the 0 */
char * strpcpy(char * t_, const char * s_, int n_)
#if 0
{ register short n = n_;
  register char * s = s_;
  register char * t = t_;
 
  if (t != null)
  { while (--n > 0 && (*t++ = *s++) != 0)
      ;
  
    if (n == 0)
      *t = 0;
  }
  return t_;
}
#else
{ return strpcpypfx(t_, s_, n_-1, 0);
}
#endif

/* ################# string match routines ##################### */

char bad_strmatch;

const char * com_match(const char * t_, const char * s_, int mask)

{ register int tix = 0;
  register const char * s = s_;
  register char ch;

#if CHARCODE != ASCII
  if (mask == 0x20)
    for (; *s != 0 && (ch = t_[tix]) != 0 && toupper(ch) == toupper(*s); ++s)
      ++tix;
  else 
#endif
    for (; *s != 0 && (ch = t_[tix]) != 0 && (ch | mask) == (*s | mask); ++s)
      ++tix;
  bad_strmatch = *s;
  return &t_[tix];
}

/* replace the last entry in dir by file */
/* t can equal dir */

char * pathcat(char * t, int bufsz, const char * dir, const char * file)
    
{ register int tix;

  if (dir[0] == '.' && dir[1] == '/' && dir[2] == '.' && dir[3] == '.' && dir[4] == '/')
    dir += 2;

  if (file[0] == '/' || file[0] == '\\')
    strpcpy(t, file, bufsz);
  else
  { for (tix = -1; ++tix < bufsz - 1 && dir[tix] != 0; )
      t[tix] = dir[tix];

    t[tix] = 0;
   
    while (1)
    { while (--tix >= 0 && t[tix] != '/' && t[tix] != '\\') /* strip back to / */
        ;

      if (tix > 0)
      { if (t[tix-1] != '.' &&
            file[0] == '.'  && file[1] == '.' && file[2] == '/')
        { for (file = &file[2]; *++file == '/';)        /* strip forward to non / */
            ;
          continue;
        }
      }

      break;
    }
  
  { int six = 0;
    for (; ++tix < bufsz - 1 && file[six] != 0; ++six)
      t[tix] = file[six];

    t[tix] = 0;
  }}
  return t;
}



int name_mode(const char * s)

{   struct stat fstat_;
    if (stat(s, &fstat_) != OK)
      return 0;
    return fstat_.st_mode;
}

#define fexist(fn) name_mode(fn)


static char fspec[256+2];   /* full path spec to search */

bool fex_path(const char * dir, const char * file)
    
{ if (dir != nullptr)
  { char * pc = pathcat(&fspec[0], sizeof(fspec), dir, file);
    if (fexist(pc))
      return true;
  }
  
  return false;  
}

#define INTWIDTH (sizeof(int) * 3)


char * int_asc(int i)
            /* integer to translate to a string */
{
  static char result[INTWIDTH+2];
    memset(&result, ' ', INTWIDTH); 

{   char *sp = &result[INTWIDTH+1];
    int v = i;      /* sign of resulting number */

    if (v < 0)
      v = -v;

    *sp = 0;
    do 
    { *(--sp) = '0' + v % 10;   /* and install the new digit */
      v = v / 10;
    } while (v);

    if (i < 0)
      *(--sp) = '-';        /* and install the minus sign */

    return sp;
}}



char * g_invokenm;


void flook_init(char * cmd)

{ g_invokenm = _strdup(cmd);

  if (g_invokenm[0] == '"')
  { ++g_invokenm;
    g_invokenm[strlen(g_invokenm)-1] = 0;
  }
{ char * sp;
  for (sp = g_invokenm; *sp != 0 && *sp != ' '; ++sp)
    if (*sp == '\\')
      *sp = '/';

  if (*sp != 0)
    *sp = 0;

}}



/*  wh == I => 
    Look up the existence of a file in the current working directory || 
    along the include path in the INCLDIRS environment variable. 
    wh == E => 
    Look up the existence of a file in the current working directory || 
    along the normal $PATH
    else 
      if wh is in uppercase then look first in the $HOME directory
      always look up a file along the normal $PATH.
*/
const char * flook(char wh, const char * fname)

{          char uwh = toupper(wh);
  register char *path;  /* environmental PATH variable */
//         char buf[100];

    if (fexist(fname))
      return fname;
                              /* if we have an absolute path check only there! */
    if (*fname == '\\' || *fname == '/' ||
        *fname != 0 && fname[1] == ':')
      return nullptr;

    //loglog1("not so far %s", fname);

    if (fname != g_invokenm)
  { if (fex_path(flook('E', g_invokenm), fname))
        return fspec;
    }

    path = getenv("PATH");

    if (path != nullptr)
      for (; *path != 0; ++path)
      { int ix;

        if (path[0] == '-' && path[1] == 'I'
         || path[0] == '.' && path[1] == '/')
          path += 2;

/*      fspec[0] = 0;
            if (inclmod != nullptr && path[0] != '/')
              strcpy(&fspec[0], inclmod);
*/
        for (ix = -1; ix < (int)sizeof(fspec)-2 &&
                       *path != 0
                   && *path != PATHCHR
                      ; )
          fspec[++ix] = *path++;
        
        if (path[-1] != DIRSEPCHAR)
          fspec[++ix] = '/';
            
        fspec[ix+1] = 0;            
/*  { char buf[200];
      strcat(strcat((buf, "PATHE "),fspec);
      MessageBox(nullptr, buf, "pe",MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION);
    } */
        if (fex_path(fspec, fname))
          return fspec;

        if (*path == 0)
          break;
      }

    return nullptr; /* no such luck */
}



char * mkTempName (/*out*/char *buf, const char *name)
{
#ifdef _CONVDIR_CHAR
 #define DIRY_CHAR _CONVDIR_CHAR
#else
 #define DIRY_CHAR DIRSEPCHAR
#endif
    static const char *tmpDir = NULL ;
                 char c2[2];
    const  char * td = tmpDir != NULL ? tmpDir : (char *)getenv("TEMP");

    c2[0] = c2[1] = 0;

    if (td == NULL)
#if (defined _DOS) || (defined _WIN32)
                        /* the C drive : better than ./ as ./ could be on a CD-Rom etc */
        td = "c:\\" ;
#else
        td = "./" ;
#endif
    else
        if (td[strlen(td)-1] != DIRY_CHAR)
            c2[0] = DIRY_CHAR;
    
    tmpDir = td;
    concat(buf,td,c2,"me",int_asc(_getpid()),name,0);

    return &buf[strlen(buf)];
}


#define DUMMY_STDIN_FILE         "stdin.~~~" 

HANDLE CreateF(char * filenm)

{ int gen = GENERIC_WRITE;
    int share = FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
    int cmd = CREATE_ALWAYS;
    HANDLE Hdl;
    int ct = 2;

    (void)mkTempName(filenm, DUMMY_STDIN_FILE);
    
    for (; ;)
    {   Hdl = CreateFile(filenm,gen,share,NULL,
                                            cmd,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
        if (--ct == 0)
            break;
        if (Hdl >= 0)                   /* VALID_HANDLE_VALUE */
            CloseHandle(Hdl);

        gen = GENERIC_READ;
        share = FILE_SHARE_READ;
        cmd = OPEN_ALWAYS;
    }

    return Hdl;
}


bool v_opt = false;

void mbwrite(const char * msg)

{ if (v_opt)
        printf("%s\n", msg);
}



void flagerr(const char * fmt)

{ DWORD ec = GetLastError();
    fprintf(stderr, fmt, ec);
}


void ErrorMessage(const char *str)  //display detailed error info
{   LPVOID msg;
  FormatMessage(
              FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
              NULL,
              GetLastError(),
              MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
              (LPTSTR) &msg,
              0,
              NULL
               );
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n",str, (const char*)msg);
  LocalFree(msg);
}


void setMyConsoleIP()

{ HANDLE ConsIn = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );
  if (ConsIn < 0)                                       /* INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE */
    flagerr("Piperr %d");

/* SetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE, g_ConsIn ); */
  if (0 == SetConsoleMode(ConsIn, ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT))
    flagerr("PipeC %d");
}


class Pipe
{ public:
    enum Modes {    WL_IHAND = 1,
                                WL_SHELL = 2,
                                WL_AWAIT_PROMPT = 4,
                                WL_HOLD  = 8,
                                WL_CNC   = CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
                                WL_CNPG  = CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP,
                                WL_SPAWN   = 0x1000,
                                WL_SHOWW     = 0x2000,
                                WL_NOIHAND = 0x4000 };

    typedef unsigned int CmdMode;

    static int menu[4];

#if _MSC_VER >= 1900
  static_assert(WL_CNC > WL_HOLD && WL_CNPG > WL_HOLD);
#endif

    static
     Cc WinLaunch(Cc & sysRet, CmdMode flags,
                              const char *app = nullptr, const char * ca = nullptr, 
                    const char * in_data = nullptr, 
                    HANDLE ip = 0, const char *outfile = 0);        // char *outErr,
};

Cc Pipe::WinLaunch(Cc & sysRet, CmdMode flags,
                                     const char *app, const char * ca, 
                           const char * in_data, 
                           HANDLE ip, const char *outfile)  // char *outErr,
{ char buff[1024];           //i/o buffer
    const char * fapp = app == nullptr ? nullptr : flook('P', app);
    
    if      (fapp != nullptr)                   // never use comspec
        app = fapp;
    else if (flags & WL_SHELL)
    {   const char * comSpecName = (char*)getenv("COMSPEC");
        if (comSpecName == nullptr)
            comSpecName = "cmd.exe";

        if (ca == nullptr)
        { app = nullptr;
            ca = comSpecName;
        }
        else                                    /* Create the command line */
        { int len = strlen(concat(buff," /c \"", app == nullptr ? "" : app,0));
            char * dd = buff+len;
            char ch;
            char prev = 'A';
            const char * ss = ca;
            if (len+strlen(ss) >= sizeof(buff))
                return -1;

            for (; (ch = *ss++); prev = ch)
            {   if (ch == '/' &&                                        // &&!(flags & LAUNCH_LEAVENAMES)
                      (in_range(toupper(prev), 'A','Z')
                  || in_range(prev, '0', '9')
                    ||                  prev == '_'  || prev == ' '))
                    ch = '\\';
        
                if (ch == '"')
                    *dd++ = '\\';
                *dd++ = ch;
            }

            *dd = '"';
            dd[1] = 0;
            ca = buff;
            app = comSpecName;
        }
    }
    
    if (app != NULL && ca != NULL && ca[0] != ' ')
        return -1000;

{ int use_data = ip != 0 || in_data != nullptr;
    HANDLE newstdin = ip;                               //pipe handles
  HANDLE newstdout = 0;
  HANDLE write_stdin = 0;
  HANDLE read_stdout = 0;
  STARTUPINFO si;
//SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;               //security information for pipes
  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
  sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
  sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = nullptr;
  sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;         //allow inheritable handles

//memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    if (flags & WL_SHOWW)
    { si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
    }

    if (flags & WL_SPAWN)
    {   if (CreatePipe(&read_stdout,&newstdout,&sa,0))  //create stdout pipe
            mbwrite("Created RSO");
        else
      { ErrorMessage("CreatePipe");
        return -1001;
      }
    
        if (CreatePipe(&newstdin,&write_stdin,&sa,0))   //create stdin pipe
            mbwrite("Created WSO");
        else
        {   ErrorMessage("CreatePipe");
            CloseHandle(newstdout);
            CloseHandle(read_stdout);
            return -1000;
    }

//  GetStartupInfo(&si);      //set startupinfo for the spawned process
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
      si.hStdOutput = newstdout;
      si.hStdError = newstdout;     //set the new handles for the child process
      si.hStdInput = newstdin;
//  si.lpTitle = "Emsub";
#if 0
        if (si.hStdOutput != 0)
        {   HANDLE cur_proc = GetCurrentProcess();
                                 
            BOOL s = DuplicateHandle(cur_proc,si.hStdOutput,
                                                             cur_proc,&si.hStdError,0,TRUE,
                                                             DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS) ;
        }
      // mbwrite("IHAND");
#endif    
      flags |= WL_IHAND;
    }
    else
    {   if (si.hStdInput <= 0 && !use_data && (flags & WL_NOIHAND) == 0)
        { char  dummyInFile[NFILEN] ;                        /* Dummy input file */
            newstdin = CreateF(dummyInFile);
            si.hStdInput = newstdin;
        }
        if (si.hStdOutput <= 0 && outfile)
        {   
            newstdout = CreateFile(outfile,GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_WRITE,&sa,
                                                                CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY,nullptr);
            si.hStdOutput = newstdout;
            if (si.hStdOutput < 0)
                fprintf(stderr,"CFOut Failed\n");
        }
        if (si.hStdInput > 0 || si.hStdOutput > 0)
            si.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    }

    if (v_opt)
  { printf(app == nullptr ? "<no app>" : "%s\n", app);
        printf(ca == nullptr ? "<no args>" : "%s\n", ca);
        printf("%s\n", int_asc((int)si.hStdOutput));
    }
                                                              //spawn the child process
  if (!CreateProcess(app,
                     (char*)ca,
                     nullptr,nullptr,
                                         (flags & WL_IHAND),
                         flags & (WL_CNPG+WL_CNC),
                     nullptr,nullptr,&si,&pi))
  { ErrorMessage("CreateProcess");
    if (newstdin != 0) CloseHandle(newstdin);
    if (newstdout != 0) CloseHandle(newstdout);
    if (read_stdout != 0) CloseHandle(read_stdout);
    if (write_stdin != 0) CloseHandle(write_stdin);
    return -1002;
  }
  
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

{   DWORD exit = 0;             //process exit code
  DWORD bread;  //bytes read
  DWORD avail;  //bytes available
  int got_ip = 0;
  int clamp = 4;
  int iter = 0;
  int end = 0;
    int sct = 6;
    int sentz = 0;

    if (!(flags & WL_SPAWN))
    {
//  int ct = 200000;
        for (;;)
        { DWORD procStatus = WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 200);
            if (procStatus == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
            { // millisleep(100);
//          if (--ct >= 0)
//          if (!typahead() /* && (TTbreakFlag != 0)*/) 
//              continue;
            }
        { Cc cc = (procStatus != WAIT_FAILED);
            if (cc)
            { cc = GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess,&exit);
              if (cc == 0)
                flagerr("GECP %d");
                else
                { // mbwrite("Exitting");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }}
        mbwrite("Exit Whole");
    }
    else 
    { char fbuff[512];
        char lbuff[512];
        const char * ipstr = in_data == nullptr ? "" : in_data;
    FILE * op = outfile == nullptr ? NULL_OP : fopen(outfile, "w");
    int append_nl = *ipstr != 0;
        
        if (read_stdout == 0)
        { mbwrite("Int Err");
            return -1;
        }

      for(;;++iter)      //main program loop
      { Sleep(250);
      { Cc cc = PeekNamedPipe(read_stdout,buff,1023,&bread,&avail,nullptr);
          if      (cc == 0)
            flagerr("PNP %d");
        else
        {   //mbwrite(int_asc(avail+10000));
                            //check to see if there is any data to read from stdout
            if (bread != 0)
            { int done = 0;
                buff[bread] = 0;
//              mbwrite(buff);
              while (done < (int)avail)
              { cc = ReadFile(read_stdout,buff,1023,&bread,nullptr);
                      if (cc == 0)
                    {   flagerr("PNP %d");
                        break;
                    }
                    if (bread == 0)
                        break;
                  done += bread;
                  buff[bread] = 0;
                        got_ip = 1;
                if      (op != nullptr)
                  fputs(buff, op);
                else if (v_opt)
                            printf("In: %s",buff);
                }
            }
            }
        cc = GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess,&exit); //while the process is running
        if (cc == 0)
        {   flagerr("GECP %d");
            if (--clamp <= 0)
                break;
        }
        else if (exit != STILL_ACTIVE)
        { mbwrite(int_asc(exit));
          break;
        }

            if (sentz && iter > 10)     // 4 seconds
            { if (--sentz <= 0)
                { sentz = 1;
                    break;
                }
                continue;
            }

            mbwrite("Testing");

        if ((flags & WL_AWAIT_PROMPT) && !got_ip && !_kbhit())
          continue;

            mbwrite("Getting");

            if (*ipstr == 0)
        {   if (ip != 0)
            { unsigned long rct;
                cc = ReadFile(ip,fbuff,sizeof(fbuff)-1,&rct,nullptr);
                    if (cc == 0)
                        ip = 0;
                    else
                    { ipstr = fbuff;
                        fbuff[rct] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        {   int sl = *ipstr;
            if (sl != 0)
        { char * ln = lbuff-1;
            --ipstr;
          while (*++ipstr != 0 && *ipstr != '\r' && *ipstr != '\n')
            *++ln = *ipstr;

                if (*ipstr == '\r' && ipstr[1] == '\n')
                    ++ipstr;
          if (*ipstr != 0)
            *++ln = *ipstr++;
          else
          { *++ln = '\n';
            mbwrite("Ends");
          }
          sl = ln + 1 - lbuff;
            if (sl > 1)
            { if      (lbuff[sl-1] == 'Z' - '@')
                    sentz = 8;
                else if (lbuff[sl-1] != '\n' && append_nl)
                { lbuff[sl++] = '\n';
                    append_nl = 0;
            }
                }
        }
        
        if (sl == 0 && sentz == 0)
        { sentz = 8;
            lbuff[sl++] = 'Z' -'@';
          mbwrite("Z");
        }
#if 0
        --sct;
            if (sct >= 0)
          { char sch = lbuff[sl];
            lbuff[sl] = 0;
            mlwrite("Sending %d %x %s",sl, lbuff[sl-1], lbuff);
                mbwrite(lastmesg);
            lbuff[sl] = sch;
          }
#endif
        cc = WriteFile(write_stdin,lbuff,sl,&bread,nullptr); //send it to stdin
        if (cc == 0)
            ErrorMessage("WriteFile");
//    else
//    { mlwrite("Sent %d",bread);
//          mbwrite(lastmesg);
//      }         

            lbuff[0] = 0;                       // Conceal data
            lbuff[1] = 0;
            lbuff[2] = 0;
    }}}
        if (op != NULL_OP)
            fclose(op);
    }
  
//printf("Exitted %d\n", exit);
  
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(newstdin);            //clean stuff up
  CloseHandle(newstdout);
  CloseHandle(read_stdout);
  CloseHandle(write_stdin);
    setMyConsoleIP();

  sysRet = sentz ? -1 : (Cc)exit;
  return sentz ? -1 : OK;
}}}


#define STANDALONE 1

#if STANDALONE

void explain(void)

{ fputs(
 "launch [-wh # | -f #] [-p app] [-a args] [-d data] [-i [file]] [-o file]\n"
 "    -wh #     Which command mode\n"
 "    -f  #     command mode\n"
 "    -p  app   App\n"
 "    -a  args  Args\n"
 "    -d  data  Data to pipe in\n"
 "    -o  file  File to receive output\n"
 "    -i [file] (Also)take data from stdin\n"
 "    -v        Verbose\n", stdout);
    exit(0);
}


int Pipe::menu[4]= { (int)(WL_SPAWN | WL_CNC | WL_AWAIT_PROMPT),
                                         WL_SHELL | WL_CNPG | WL_NOIHAND,   //  | WL_SHOWW,
                                         WL_SPAWN | WL_IHAND | WL_HOLD | WL_CNC,
                                         WL_IHAND | WL_HOLD | WL_SHELL
                                     };

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{ if (argc <= 1)
  { explain();
  }
  
{ int argsleft = argc - 1;
  char ** argv_ = &argv[1];

    short wh_opt = 0;
    int f_opt = 0;
    char * app = nullptr;
    char * args = nullptr;
    char * indata = nullptr;
    char * infile = nullptr;
    char * outfile = nullptr;
    bool usestdin_opt = false;
    
  for (; argsleft > 0 && argv_[0][0] == '-'; --argsleft)
  { char * flgs = &argv_[0][1]; 
    ++argv_;
    if (*flgs != 0)
    {   if      (*flgs == 'i')
        { if (argsleft == 1)
                usestdin_opt = true;
            else
            {   infile = *(argv_++);
                --argsleft;
            }
            continue;
        }
          else if (*flgs == 'v')
            {   v_opt = true;
            continue;
        }
            else
        {   if (argsleft == 1)
                explain();
        }
        switch(*flgs)
        { case 'w': if (flgs[1] != 'h')
                                    explain();
                                wh_opt = atoi(*(argv_));
                                break;
            case 'f':   f_opt = atoi(*(argv_));
                                break;
            case 'p':   app = *(argv_);
                                break;
            case 'a':   args = *(argv_);
                                break;
            case 'd':   indata = *(argv_);
                                break;
            case 'o':   outfile = *(argv_);
                                break;
            default:    explain();
        }
        ++argv_;
        --argsleft;
        }
  }

    if (f_opt == 0 && wh_opt == 0)
        explain();
                
    if (wh_opt > sizeof(Pipe::menu) / sizeof(int))
        explain();

    if (wh_opt)
        if (f_opt)
            explain();
        else
            f_opt = Pipe::menu[wh_opt - 1];

    HANDLE ip = infile != nullptr
                                    ? CreateFile(infile,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,nullptr,
                                                                OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,nullptr) :
                            usestdin_opt ? GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE ) :
                                                        0;
    Cc rc;
    Cc cc = Pipe::WinLaunch(rc, f_opt, app, args, indata, ip, outfile);
    if (cc == -1)
        printf("Gave up\n");
    else
        printf("Cc %d Rc %d\n", cc, rc);
    return OK;
}}

#endif
```